# I want all PDF or DOCs to come first in the output

Tags: python, automation

So I came up with this code that sorts out PDF and DOC files, I am getting the output but I need then to be in order. I want all PDF or DOCs to come first in order.

```
import os, sys, re

pdf = re.compile(r'.*Shandeep.*\.pdf')
doc = re.compile(r'.*Shandeep.*\.doc')

for r, d, f in os.walk(r'/Users/shandeepkm/Desktop/Networking materials'):
    for items1 in f:
        match1 = re.findall(pdf, items1)
        match2 = re.findall(doc, items1)
        if match1 or match2:
           print items1
```

The output is:

```
  Shandeep_HERE.doc
  Shandeep_HERE.pdf
  Shandeep_R_OpS.doc
Shandeep KM AppQA.doc
Shandeep KM AppQA.pdf
Shandeep KM NetQA.doc
Shandeep KM NetQA.pdf
Shandeep KM Resume copy.doc
Shandeep KM Resume.doc
Shandeep KM Resume.pdf
Shandeep KM ResumeQA.doc
ShandeepResumeAm.doc
ShandeepResumeAm.pdf
ShandeepResumeC.doc
ShandeepResumeC.pdf
```

I want it to be in a order similar to:

```
  Shandeep_HERE.doc
  Shandeep_R_OpS.doc
Shandeep KM NetQA.doc
Shandeep KM AppQA.doc
Shandeep KM Resume copy.doc
Shandeep KM Resume.doc
Shandeep KM AppQA.pdf
  Shandeep_HERE.pdf 
Shandeep KM NetQA.pdf
Shandeep KM Resume.pdf
ShandeepResumeAm.pdf
ShandeepResumeC.pdf
```

Comment: I have *no idea* what your expected output is, as I cannot begin to fathom what you are trying to do. Can you add an expected output please?

Comment: @Martijn: Added the expecting output.

Comment: Where is the "**with each counts at the end**" in your desired output example?

Comment: If you could see below someone answered precisely what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all PDF or DOCs to come first

The order is not defined by the order you defined your Regular Expressions.

You will need to do some post processing if you wish to print in order.

```
import os, sys, re

pdf_list = []
doc_list = []

pdf = re.compile(r'.*Shandeep.*\.pdf')
doc = re.compile(r'.*Shandeep.*\.doc')

for r, d, f in os.walk(r'/Users/shandeepkm/Desktop/Networking materials'):
    for items1 in f:
        match1 = re.findall(pdf, items1)
        match2 = re.findall(doc, items1)
        if match1:
            pdf_list.append(match1)
        if match2:
           doc_list.append(match2)
```

> with each counts at the end.

Use `collections.Counter()` for this:

```
from collections import Counter
counter_pdf = Counter(pdf_list)
counter_doc = Counter(pdf_doc)

print counter_pdf  # Counter({'ShandeepResumeAm.doc': 2, 'ShandeepResumeAm.pdf': 1, ....})
```

Answer (score 1):

First write a for loop that iterates over all the file names. Then, keep all the filenames you want in an array. Loop over each index of the array like so

```
for x in range(len(extensionslist)):
    for root, dir, files in os.walk('[directory path]'):
        for file in files:
            if extensionslist[x] in file:
                print file
```

any type of ordering you would like to do, you can do on the list, such as alphabetize would be

```
sorted(extensionslist).
```

P.S. I originall wrote sort which is wrong. To alphabetize the array you need to write sorted()